# Searching for occurrences of multiple words in a text file

Tags: python, list, count

I would like to be able to search a text file for multiple words and be able to receive a count of how many times those words occurred in the text file. Or to search for how many times words in a list occur in a text file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [count()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count)

```
myString = "hello world hello stack overflow"

searchWords = ["hello", "stack"]

for word in searchWords:
    print(f"Word '{word}' appeared {myString.count(word)} time/s.")
```

Output:

```
Word 'hello' appeared 2 time/s.
Word 'stack' appeared 1 time/s.
```